# Python-coded neural network does not learn properly

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

My network is not trained to recognize inputs separately, it either outputs the averaged result or becomes biased to one particular output. What am I doing wrong?

```
import numpy as np

sigmoid = lambda x: 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
sigmoid_der = lambda x: sigmoid(x) * (1 - sigmoid(x))
ReLU = lambda x: np.maximum(0, x)
ReLU_der = lambda x: x > 0


class NeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self, shape: tuple):
        self.layers = len(shape) # The amount layers
        self.shape = shape # The amount of neurons per each layer
        self.weights = [
            np.array([np.random.rand(shape[l - 1]) for _ in range(shape[l])])
            for l in range(1, self.layers)
        ] # A list of matrices of weights connecting neighbouring layers
        self.weighted_sums = [np.zeros(l) for l in shape]
        self.activations = [np.zeros(l) for l in shape]

    def inspect(self):
        print("=============NeuralNetwork===============")
        print(f"Shape: {self.shape}")
        print(f"Weights: {self.weights}")
        print(f"Activations: {self.activations}")

    def forward_prop(self, X):
        self.activations[0] = X
        for l in range(1, self.layers):
            self.weighted_sums[l] = self.weights[l - 1] @ self.activations[l - 1]
            self.activations[l] = sigmoid(self.weighted_sums[l])

    def backprop(self, X, Y):
        delta = [np.empty(self.shape[l]) for l in range(1, self.layers)] # Here errors get stored
        delta[-1] = (Y - self.activations[-1]) * sigmoid_der(self.weighted_sums[-1]) # The output error
        for l in reversed(range(self.layers - 2)): # The errors get backpropagated
            delta[l] = self.weights[l + 1].T @ delta[l + 1] * sigmoid_der(self.weighted_sums[l])
        for l in range(self.layers - 1): # The weights get updated online
            for j in range(self.shape[l + 1]):
                self.weights[l][j] -= 0.1 * self.activations[l + 1][j] * delta[l][j]


nn = NeuralNetwork((2, 2, 1))

X = np.array([
    [1, 0],
    [0, 1],
    [1, 1],
    [0, 0]
])

Y = np.array([
    [1],
    [1],
    [0],
    [0]
])

# I train my network by randomly picking an example from my training sets
for _ in range(1000):
    i = np.random.randint(0, 4)
    nn.forward_prop(X[i])
    nn.backprop(X[i], Y[i])

for x in X:
    nn.forward_prop(x)
    print(nn.activations[-1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrix math of backpropagation is quite tough. It is especially confusing that the length of the lists of weight matrices and deltas (actually the list of bias arrays too) should be one less than the amount of layers in a network which makes indexing confusing. Apparently, the problem was due to misindexing. Finally it works!

```
import numpy as np

sigmoid = lambda x: 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
sigmoid_der = lambda x: sigmoid(x) * (1 - sigmoid(x))
ReLU = lambda x: np.maximum(0, x)
ReLU_der = lambda x: x > 0


class NeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self, shape: tuple):
        self.layers = len(shape)
        self.shape = shape
        self.weights = [
            np.array([2 * np.random.random(shape[l - 1]) - 1 for _ in range(shape[l])])
            for l in range(1, self.layers)
        ]
        self.biases = [np.zeros(l) for l in shape[1:]]
        self.weighted_sums = [None for l in shape]
        self.activations = [None for l in shape]
        self.deltas = [None for l in shape[1:]]

    def inspect(self):
        print("=============NeuralNetwork===============")
        print(f"Shape: {self.shape}")
        print(f"Weights: {self.weights}")
        print(f"Activations: {self.activations}")

    def forward_prop(self, X):
        self.activations[0] = X
        for l in range(1, self.layers):
            self.weighted_sums[l] = self.weights[l - 1] @ self.activations[l - 1] + self.biases[l - 1]
            self.activations[l] = sigmoid(self.weighted_sums[l])

    def backprop(self, X, Y, lr):
        self.deltas[-1] = (Y - self.activations[-1]) * sigmoid_der(self.weighted_sums[-1])
        for l in range(self.layers - 2, 0, -1):
            self.deltas[l - 1] = self.weights[l].T @ self.deltas[l] * sigmoid_der(self.weighted_sums[l])
        for l in range(self.layers - 1):
            for j in range(self.shape[l + 1]):
                self.weights[l][j] += lr * self.activations[l] * self.deltas[l][j]
            self.biases[l] += self.deltas[l]

    def train(self, X, Y, lr, epochs):
        for e in range(epochs):
            if not e % 1000: self.test(X)
            i = np.random.randint(len(X))
            self.forward_prop(X[i])
            self.backprop(X[i], Y[i], lr)

    def test(self, X):
        print()
        for x in X:
            self.forward_prop(x)
            print(x, self.activations[-1])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    nn = NeuralNetwork((2, 3, 2, 1))

    X = np.array([
        [1, 0],
        [0, 1],
        [1, 1],
        [0, 0]
    ])

    Y = np.array([
        [1],
        [1],
        [0],
        [0]
    ])

    nn.train(X, Y, 0.4, 20000)
    nn.test(X)
```